# How to Fix Acer E-11 stuck in Automatic Repair Mode after Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS install?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on my Acer Aspire E11, as Windows 10 is getting too bloated and slow. I don't want a dual-boot, but there's still a caveat: The laptop comes with a pre-installed recovery partition which I do not want to wipe.

In order to preserve the option to go back, I chose not to wipe the disc (and risk wiping the recovery partition), but to set up custom partitions instead. I set up a primary ext4 partition for , a logical swap partition and a logical ext4 \home partition.

The installation went well, but when I try to boot up the system, my laptop goes to automatic repair mode and tries to restore Win10. I suspect that there is something weird going on with the UEFI, but can't really identify the issue. Any help is appreciated, as the computer is now effectively unusable.

Comment: You might find these links helpful. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Acer_Aspire_E11_Series  and https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=181755. The Linux mint link may be all you need, adjusting some firmware settings. The Arch wiki link is more end to end and assumes you are installing Arch but contains good information. Elsewhere it seems the wifi can be problematic but on MX Linux it works without any additional steps. Good luck